# Permanently Dismiss "New iCloud Terms and Conditions" on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: icloud, high-sierra

I don't use and don't plan on ever using iCloud. I'm not sure I even remember the password for my account. Apple keeps popping up the "New iCloud Terms and Conditions" notification on my mac and I have been clicking it every day and the immediately quitting system preferences. There must be a better way to remove it. I can't drag it away and there is no "later" option.

Comment: Most people just agree then ignore it. The iCloud structure is so deeply embedded in the Apple ethos that it's easier to ignore than try to bypass.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is requesting all the time as your already logged into iCloud.

If you go to:
Apple -> System Preferences -> iCloud
Then click 'sign out'

MacOS will not ask for you to agree to the iCloud T&Cs anymore.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me as on 10.14.6. Even though I am not logged in through iCloud in system permissions, it continues to ask me to accept the permissions (recently upgraded from 10.11 and experienced this problem afterwards).

Comment: this problem has become worse after the upgrade to MacOS CATALINA. The popup is sticky and refuses to go away no matter how many times you accept the terms and conditions.

Comment: I wonder if the iCloud terms are less legally binding as a result of Apple nagging so heavily on this and not allowing a way to decline it permanently.